# Yii2 Add a scope to a AR after executing find()

Tags: yii2

I have following scenario:

There is a `project` table and a `task` table. `Project hasmany Task`.

So, now I do a `Project::find()->all()`. So I get a `$projects` object and can access the related tasks via `$projects[0]->task`.

But in my view I want also output all tasks where `done = 0` and the amount of tasks that are expiring in the next 7 days. So is there a possibility, to add for example a scope on `$projects[0]->task`?

What would the Yii2 way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found it my own. It´s possible to get the relation via $projects[0]->getTasks() and then I get the ActiveQuery to add a new scope.

Answer (score 0):

[The Yii Active Record](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-active-record.md) methods based on chunking (they return instance of class, another words `$this` variable). So you can find necessary `tasks` like this:

```
Project:find()->joinWith('task')->where(['done' => 0])->all();
```

Or use [The Query Builder](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-query-builder.md) to get `tasks`.

```
$query = new Query();
$pTable = Project::tableName();
$tTable = Task::tableName();
$query->select($pTable.'.id AS project_id, '.$tTable.'.id as task_id, done');
$query->from($pTable);
$query->innerJoin($tTable, $pTable.'.id = '.$tTable.'.project_id');
$query->where(['done' => 0]);
$result = $query->all();
```

But in second case you need to add more actions to group your all tasks to parent project.

For more details, please, see the [Yii documentation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md).